# What is the difference between CREATE TABLE and CREATE COLUMN TABLE in SAP HANA

Tags: hana

Pretty much as the title states: What is the difference between `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE COLUMN TABLE`?

Both seemingly create a table, so what is the difference?

Comment: I´m pretty sure that you are wrong with your assumption. CREATE TABLE is a very SQL style to create a table. As far as I could google within minutes, there is no "COLUMN TABLE" statement. But - you can prove me wrong.

Comment: CREATE TABLE can also be used in SAP HANA: https://help.sap.com/viewer/7c78579ce9b14a669c1f3295b0d8ca16/Cloud/en-US/20d58a5f75191014b2fe92141b7df228.html but there is also the `COLUMN TABLE` in Hana which creates a Table

Comment: I am no expert but do you mean `CREATE COLUMN TABLE`? At least that's what documented in the link you provided. `CREATE TABLE` can mean both row based and column based, depends on whether the table is temp or non-temp. `CREATE <table_type> TABLE` gives you the option to manually choose `COLUMN` (or `ROW`).

Comment: As I mentioned, there is no "COLUMN TABLE" statement, but a table type "COLUMN". The of Lars B. is very clear. And you should mark it as the valid answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SAP HANA supports tables that store data in a **column store** or a **row store**.

These refer to different ways of how the database (HANA) manages the data stored in the tables.
They **do not** affect how the data can be used in a SQL statement whatsoever.

Technically, the syntax for `CREATE TABLE` in HANA has been extended to include a way to choose which of the two table types should be created:

`CREATE [COLUMN|ROW] TABLE <table_name> ...`

This means one can (and probably should) include the table type desired in any `CREATE TABLE` command, but can also choose to not do that (i.e. to keep compatibility which standard SQL).

## The default setting

Now, which table type you get when **not** specifying the table type depends on a HANA parameter in the `indexserver.ini` configuration file.
If the parameter `[sql] - [default_table_type]` is set to `row` then not specifying the table type will get a table stored in the row store. This is also the default value for the parameter up until HANA 2 SPS 03 if I'm not mistaken.

With HANA 2 SPS 04 the default for the parameter was finally changed to `column`.

## What you should use

This is important: with SAP HANA you *want* the table type to be **COLUMN** in nearly all cases.

Row store tables have very different performance and memory requirement characteristics and really only serve **very specific** data access and modification patterns.
Those patterns are for example:

- **always** full row access by selecting the complete primary key.
- high frequency of `UPDATE`s on records (think updating the same record thousands of times a second).
- records with nearly distinct records in every/most column/s that absolutely need to be in memory at all times.

For the **vast majority** of all use cases and data types `CREATE COLUMN TABLE` is the **right** choice in SAP HANA.
Column store tables support compression, partitioning, memory displacement, and many other techniques that are not available for row store tables.

## The difference it makes to your programs

And yet, both table types "look and feel" the same to any SQL command.
To give an analogy, other DBMS support different table types like "cluster" or "heap" that affect how data gets stored internally while the tables can be used regardless of the chosen type.
The HANA setting for column or row store is a similar choice about internal storage.

All that (and a lot more) is of course documented (e.g. [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.04/en-US/20d44b4175191014a940afff4b47c7ea.html)) and explained in many different places (e.g. my book [SAP HANA Administration](https://www.sap-press.com/sap-hana-administration_3506/)).

## What column and row store is not about

Note that the choice between column or row store has nothing to do with whether the table is a *temporary* or *permanent* table. Both table types permanently persist the data as one would expect.

Of course, one can always use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` which also comes with a whole range of option... `CREATE TEMPORARY { ROW | COLUMN } TABLE | LOCAL TEMPORARY { ROW | COLUMN } TABLE` but for this answer let's pretend we didn't see that to save our sanity.

## Take away

It's quite important to understand that HANA has those two fundamentally different implementations of in-memory tables.
Make sure you don't accidentally (by using the default) create row store tables for your mass data analytics or really for most use cases.
Whenever you're unsure about the table type, start off with a **column** store table and see if that works for your use case. Should you actually have a use case for which row store is the better option, you can (nearly) always convert a table from one storage type to the other via an `ALTER TABLE` command.